# Can't get value from JSON Data - YouTube API -

Tags: java, android, json, youtube

I'v try to get an value from a json data (YouTube V3 API).

```
String jsonText = readFromUrl(channerUrl);// channerUrl = Youtube V3 API Link

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);

System.out.println(json.getString("videoId"));
```

But i have this in my log :

```
I/System.out: org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId
```

The data from YouTube is :

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"xxxx"",
 "nextPageToken": "xxx",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 321,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
     "items": [
      {
       "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
       "etag": "\"xxxx"",
       "id": "xxxx",
       "contentDetails": {
        "videoId": "The Value Want"
       }
      }
     ]
}
```

Why i have `No value for videoId` ? 
Thank you

**EDIT (didn't work too) :** *(jsonText) is the link of the JSON Data*

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);


        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("items");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
            list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("contentDetails"));
            System.out.println(json.getString("contentDetails"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `videoId` is under `items` object.
Get `item` first then get its `first child` then fet the `videoId`

Edit: use

```
array.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("contentDetails").getString("videoId")
```

And remove the `println` line

Then outside the loop just print the list that contains the `videoId`s

Comment: Ok, so `videoID` is in `contentDetails` who is in `items` ? How i can get `item` first ?

Comment: Find getObject and getArray methods and use them

Comment: I've edited my first post, i have try with getArray methods but that didn't work too

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);


            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray array = null;
            try {
                array = json.getJSONArray("items");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
                // list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("contentDetails"));
                try {
                    System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("contentDetails").getString("videoId"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
    {
        JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(strValue);
        JSONArray items = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
        String nextToken = mJsonObject.getString("nextPageToken").toString();

        for(int i = 0;i<items.length();i++)
        {

            JSONObject snipetts = items.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject snipet = snipetts.getJSONObject("snippet");
            JSONObject thumbnails = snipet.getJSONObject("thumbnails");
            JSONObject highImage = thumbnails .getJSONObject("high");

            String title = snipet.get("title").toString();
            String urlImage = highImage.get("url").toString();
            String videoID = snipetts.getString("id");
            String description = snipet.getString("description");
            String publishDate = snipet.getString("publishedAt");

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```